# CSS Property white-space example for break-spaces

Tags: css, whitespace

I am finding css `white-space: break-spaces` example. I googled for 1 hours. Not found example yet! Most tutorials show exmaple for **normal, nowrap, pre, pre-wrap, pre-line**. For **break-spaces** people show like below quote from *[mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)*

> The behavior is identical to that of pre-wrap, except that:
>
> - Any sequence of preserved white space always takes up space, including at the end of the line.
> - A line breaking opportunity exists after every preserved white space character, including between white space characters.
> - Such preserved spaces take up space and do not hang, and thus affect the box’s intrinsic sizes (min-content size and max-content size).

Could anyone show me example differences between break-spaces and pre-wrap?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This example should make it a bit more clear showing how the trailing white space won't wrap with `pre-wrap`

```css
.break-spaces {
  white-space: break-spaces;
}

.pre-wrap {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

div {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  width: 150px;
}

span {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="break-spaces">
  <span>This is a test where white-space: break-spaces is being used.
  Trailing white space will wrap                                                        
  
  Test</span>
</div>

<div class="pre-wrap">
  <span>This is a test where white-space: pre-wrap is being used.
  Trailing white space will not wrap                                                    
  
  Test</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are there upsides to using `pre-wrap` in any situation?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov: Maybe. Chromium's implementation of `break-spaces` is [broken](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1261435).